# UIViewController Dealloc Checklist? My ViewControllers are stuck in RAM

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller

So I decided to go with UIViewControllers for the purpose of easy memory leak prevention.

But my UIViewControllers are not being dealloc'ed after they are dismissed. I'm building a game using SpriteKit. Most of the RAM is used by the SKScene which is not a property of GameViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

I'm sticking with apple's boilerplate code, so the scene isn't a property of GameViewController. (which should help prevent the memory leak I'm currently dealing with??)

Is there a good checklist of things needed to be done in the ViewController before ARC deallocs it finally?

So far I have:

[x] Invalidated all NSTimers once the GameViewController is finished with.

[x] Completely removed all NSNotification observers

Am I missing anything?

I've tried using the MemoryLeak instrument, it will always tell me there are zero memory leaks. And it continues to report zero memory leaks even after the app crashes due to low memory...

Comment: How are you dismissing and presenting the view controllers?

Comment: Oh wait, `deinit` is being called when the ViewController is dismissed. Does that mean ARC is working properly?

Comment: yes, it does. Why did you think your view controllers were stuck?

Comment: Deinit being called only means that your VC is being released, but if something still keeps a strong reference to any of its views they are NOT released within the VC.

Comment: Are you having more than 1 view controller. Why are you expecting it to deallocate?

In a SpriteKit the GameViewController is managing all SKScenes, so I don't understand why you want it to deallocate.